# How to create linked tables in Amazon Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

everyone! I have some problems with creating linked tables in Athena.
When I add primary or foreign key to my sql query there is an error.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `organization`( 
  `id` string PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `version` int COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `timestamp` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `tzOffset` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://test/test/'

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `users`( 
      `routinename` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
      `eventType` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
      FOREIGN KEY (organizationId) REFERENCES organization (id) COMMENT 'from deserializer')
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 
      'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
    OUTPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    LOCATION
      's3://test/test1/'
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What is the error? Can you simplify your question to highlight the specific lines that are causing the issue (for example, by removing unnecessary columns from the table definition yet still make it reproducible)? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as primary or foreign keys in Athena. Here is the documentation for what features Athena supports when creating a table: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html

Primary and foreign keys are used by RDBMSs for ensuring constraints – for example to ensure you don't insert rows with duplicate IDs, or remove rows in related tables. These are not as relevant in a system like Athena where there are no inserts or updates.